# What is this MapperListener error deploying Grails 3 prod war to Tomcat9?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, grails

Why am I getting:

> ....MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name

This is Grails 3.2.12 deploying prod war to Tomcat 9.0.21.  At the end of the war deployment these lines show up, ruining the deployment:

```
18-Jun-2019 11:34:41.702 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
18-Jun-2019 11:35:04.764 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
18-Jun-2019 11:35:04.764 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
18-Jun-2019 11:35:04.764 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
18-Jun-2019 11:35:04.764 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener.findDefaultHost Unknown default host [localhost] for service [StandardService[Catalina]]. Tomcat will not be able process HTTP/1.0 requests that do not specify a host name.
```

Virtual hosting in effect, but the problem can be exposed by just running the single war out of webapps.  Strangely, the war runs without producing these errors on some platforms running the same version of tomcat, but the WIndows 10 AWS deployment produces errors.  The app is pulling resources from JNDI.

Does this mean that some class packaged into the war is a WebApplicationInitializer?  What would that be?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because there was no <Host> defined for "localhost", as in <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">.  This is partly by design since this server should never field a request for localhost.  The MapperListener warning can be removed by defining a localhost or removing the defaultHost attribute.  I'm not sure why this warning only shows up on production war build out of Grails, whereas it does not on a development build.  But there you have it.

Comment: Removing will say the same message with null defaultHost.